# Symfony Entites import - No Metadata Classes to process

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine, entities

With Symfony 4, I want to generate Entities from an existing database but when I try to convert my `*.orm.xml` files, I get this message :

```
[OK] No Metadata Classes to process.
```

I have several `*orm.xml` files in `src/Resources/config/doctrine` :

```
ls -l src/Resources/config/doctrine/
```

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Create a bundle in `src/` :

   ```
   <?php
   namespace App;

   use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

   class App extends Bundle
   {
   }
   ```
2. In `config/bundles.php`, add :

   ```
   App\App::class => ['all' => true],
   ```
3. Execute `php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force App xml` to generate `*.orm.xml` files
4. Execute `php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src` to generate entities.

The last command return the message `No Metadata Classes to process.`.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Any idea ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I didn't understand the official documentation...

I remove the content of `src/Resources/config/doctrine` and I execute this command and my entities are generated :

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force App annotation
```

The `php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src` is not useful in this case...

**What I understood**
I generate metadata files with :

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force App xml
```

After, I can convert these `*.orm.xml` files with

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src
```

But this is not working :( I don't understand why...

But, if I do not do anything of that (don't generate metadata), and I'm doing this instead :

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force App annotation
```

This is working...

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes when you have something wrong in your YML / XML / Entity mapping files. 
Possible reason paths or names are wrong.

Comment: it's strange because it's auto-generated

Comment: but check your paths  for entities. May you manually copy files to specific directory and then try again your command.

Comment: ok i will try this when i will meet the problem again. thanks